# jQuery Animated Number Counter From Zero To Percentage Value

Tags: jquery, html, timer, counter, animator

I working on the project where I want to add jQuery Animated Number Counter From Zero To Percentage Value- Javascript Animation in the result page, values are dynamic from the database?

```js
function timer() {
  if (animator.curPercentage < animator.targetPercentage) {
    animator.curPercentage += 1;
  } else if (animator.curPercentage > animator.targetPercentage) {
    animator.curPercentage -= 1;
  }

  $(animator.outputSelector).text(animator.curPercentage + "%");

  if (animator.curPercentage != animator.targetPercentage) {
    setTimeout(timer, animator.animationSpeed)
  }
}

function PercentageAnimator() {
  this.animationSpeed = 50;
  this.curPercentage = 0;
  this.targetPercentage = 0;
  this.outputSelector = ".countPercentage";

  this.animate = function(percentage) {
    this.targetPercentage = percentage;
    setTimeout(timer, this.animationSpeed);
  }
}

var animator = new PercentageAnimator();
animator.curPercentage = 40;
animator.animate(70);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="countPercentage">98%</span>
<span class="countPercentage">92%</span>
<span class="countPercentage">12%</span>
<span class="countPercentage">67%</span>
```

The problem is that the jQuery Function `PercentageAnimator` is working but till 70 only?

How do I get dynamic value of each class `countPercentage` in `animator.animate(70)` Instead of `70`

**Jsfiddle Full Code**

```
https://jsfiddle.net/fdharsi/bx9pbLpd/10/
```

**Problem Has Been Fixed Now Here Updated jsfiddle**

```
https://jsfiddle.net/fdharsi/bx9pbLpd/11/
```

Comment: It will be great if you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it is simple HTML and jquery code

Answer (score 0):

Well you could simply wrap your `<span>` elements in a div with a class for example:

```
<div class='percents'>
    <span class="countPercentage" data-value=98">98%</span>
    <span class="countPercentage" data-value=92">92%</span>
    <span class="countPercentage" data-value=12">12%</span>
    <span class="countPercentage" data-value=67">67%</span>
</div>
```

And then you could just loop through the children of that div with JQuery like so:

```
$('.percents').children().each(function() {
    animator.animate($(this).data('value'));
});
```

You might even be able to simple do `$('.countPercentage').each()` but I haven't checked...

However this is probably not how you should be doing it... What is it you wanna do exactly ?

Comment: kindly check the full source code of jquery 
https://jsfiddle.net/fdharsi/bx9pbLpd/2/

Comment: yes, i want this type of code but kindly check how I do embed in the jquery function? https://jsfiddle.net/fdharsi/bx9pbLpd/10/